# Make a function implemented as a vDSO actually syscall?

Tags: linux, system-calls, vdso

Is there a way to cause this to happen (short of recoding every instance of the call, say `time()` to be a call to `syscall()`?

Comment: http://rr-project.org/ seems to do this.But I am not sure if you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't yet found if/when/how rr does this, but it looks like a really cool tool.

Comment: https://github.com/rr-debugger/rr/pull/1279/files#diff-26743ee03d8e643c058f9cfa835705beadaa579c3b6220cb728940b11ab6e56fR1394 It patches the VDSO region to jump to its own code.